# Not able to store "_id" as a UUID string in Mongo java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to store `_id` as a String in Mongo, but for some reason, mongo is still overriding and storing it as an `ObjectId.` Below is my Java class

```
    public class Subscription {
    @JsonProperty("subscriptionId")
        private String _id;
        private List<FilterAttribute> filterAttributes;
    }
```

Here is my code that saves the object.

```
 private final MongoCollection<Subscription> mongoCollection;
 mongoCollection.insertOne(subscription);
```

I tried a few methods but had no luck

Comment: The driver may have not recognized the `_id` field as the document id, for which you may need to annotate it using [@BsonId](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.6/apidocs/bson/org/bson/codecs/pojo/annotations/BsonId.html). Also the driver may require std POJO style getters/setters. Not sure, therefore posted as a comment ;)

Comment: @murtiko yeah that did not work :(